# Multiple deployments in same Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a unique scenario where I have to deploy two different deployments, I have created a helm chart wherein programmatically I change a part of deployment at run time (while applying charts as overrides).
My Helm Chart is very simple it consist of a namespace and a deployment.

Now, when I apply the Helm Chart first time - which on runtime overrides values of first deployment and say it has `attribute_name` it substitute to value `Var_A` as expected . It works well. It creates namespace and creates deployment with `attribute_name` having value `Var_A`. So good so far .....

...but next when I apply the Helm Chart to deploy my second deployment which needs `attribute_name` to be `Var_B` it does not get applied, reason Helm complains that namespace already exists (rightly so).

I am wondering how to implement this solution ?
Would I need a new HelmChart just for `namespace` and other HelmChart for `deployments`? Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you have a specific need to include the Namespace in the chart?  `helm install --create-namespace` can create it for you if required.  (You tagged this with "helmfile", and [that tool](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile) has a similar option to create namespaces.)

Comment: Are you using `helm install` every time? Have you tried with `helm upgrade` ?